# Fourier transform of $f^{n}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

It is true that if a function $f$ has fourier transform $\hat{f}$ then, $(\hat{f})^n =  FT(f^{n})$ (where $FT$ denotes the fourier transform). If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. The Fourier Transform of a product of functions is the convolution of their Fourier Transforms, e.g.

$$\widehat{(fg)}(x) = (\hat{f}* \hat{g})(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(x-y) \hat{g}(y) \, \mathrm{d} y. $$

Showing this is a play with the definition of the Fourier Transform, and a good exercise to do to convince yourself.

Comment: $\widehat{f \ast g} = \hat{f} \hat{g}$ the opposite direction needs the Fourier inversion theorem